# Validate (bassistance plugin) required( dependency-callback ) question

Tags: jquery, validation

On my client registration form I have the following rules

```
// Define the div containing validation messages
var container = $('#clientErrorWrapper');
// Start validation routine 
// validate the form when it is submitted
var validator = $("#frmEdit").submit(function() {
    // update underlying textarea before submit validation
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    }).validate({
    errorContainer: container,
    errorLabelContainer: $("ul", container),
    wrapper: 'li',
    // start rules (add new rules as necessary)
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true
            },
            address1: {
                required: true
            },
            city: {
                required: true
            },
            state_province: {
                required: function(element) {
                    return $("#country").val() == 'US';
                  }
            },
            postcode: {
                required: true
            },
            country: {
                required: true
            }
    // finish rules
    }
```

I would like to extend the state_province rules so that this field is required if country equals CA or AU as well, how can I achieve this please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
        state_province: {
            required: function(element) {
                var c = $("#country").val();
                return c=='US' || c=='CA' || c=='AU';
              }
        }
```

No need to get more complicated than that unless your list gets a bit longer.

If however the list grows, you can use [jQuery's .inArray()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray):

```
        state_province: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $.inArray($("#country").val(), ['US','CA','AU']) > -1;
              }
        }
```

Comment: Nick,

thanks your 1st solution works perfectly but the 2nd shows the following error in firebug invalid object initializer

Comment: @I-CRE8 - Woops, use `[]` instead of `{}` for Arrays, answer updated.

Comment: The second got me to where I needed today!  Thanks!